# Android how to match values with database

Tags: android

below is my code i just want to retrieve only taht values in list view which match with database  this line not compare value in PlayStoreApps class
if (arraylist.equals(p.packageName))   please help me.

```
                public class PlayStoreApps extends Activity implements   
      OnItemClickListener {

/* whether or not to include system apps */
private static final boolean INCLUDE_SYSTEM_APPS = false;
 DatabaseHandler db;
private ListView mAppsList;
private AppListAdapter mAdapter;
private List<App> mApps;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.games);
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);


    mAppsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.appslist);
    mAppsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    mApps = loadInstalledApps(INCLUDE_SYSTEM_APPS);

    mAdapter = new AppListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    mAdapter.setListItems(mApps);
    mAppsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    new LoadIconsTask().execute(mApps.toArray(new App[] {}));
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    final App app = (App) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    String msg = app.getTitle()
            + "\n\n"
            + "Version "
            + app.getVersionName()
            + " ("
            + app.getVersionCode()
            + ")"
            + (app.getDescription() != null ? ("\n\n" + app
                    .getDescription()) : "");

    builder.setMessage(msg)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setTitle(app.getTitle())
            .setIcon(mAdapter.getIcons().get(app.getPackageName()))
            .setPositiveButton("Launch",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void 
  onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // start the app by 
  invoking its launch intent
                            Intent i = 
 getPackageManager()

  .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                            app.getPackageName());
                            try {
                                if (i != null) {

  startActivity(i);
                                } else {
                                    i = new  
  Intent(app.getPackageName());

  startActivity(i);
                                }
                            } catch 
  (ActivityNotFoundException err) {

                            }
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void 
 onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

private List<App> loadInstalledApps(boolean includeSysApps) {
    List<App> apps = new ArrayList<App>();

    // the package manager contains the information about all installed apps
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0); 
    List arraylist = db.getAllApps();

    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = p.applicationInfo;




    if (arraylist.equals(p.packageName))

    //  if ( (p.packageName).equals(arraylist))


        {
            App app = new App();
            app.setTitle(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)
                    .toString());
            app.setPackageName(p.packageName);
            app.setVersionName(p.versionName);
            app.setVersionCode(p.versionCode);
            CharSequence description = p.applicationInfo

                    .loadDescription(packageManager);
            app.setDescription(description != null ? 
  description.toString()
                    : "");
            apps.add(app);
            // }
        }
    }
    return apps;
}

/**
 * An asynchronous task to load the icons of the installed applications.
 */
private class LoadIconsTask extends AsyncTask<App, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(App... apps) {

        Map<String, Drawable> icons = new HashMap<String, Drawable>();
        PackageManager manager = getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageManager();

        for (App app : apps) {
            String pkgName = app.getPackageName();
            Drawable ico = null;
            try {
                Intent i =  
  manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgName);
                if (i != null) {
                    ico = manager.getActivityIcon(i);
                }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Unable to find icon for package '"
                        + pkgName + "': " + 
   e.getMessage());
            }
            icons.put(app.getPackageName(), ico);
        }
        mAdapter.setIcons(icons);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

}




    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
//private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("+ 
 KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT" +  " UNIQUE " + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

     // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
//  values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

     // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, 
    null);
     if (cursor != null)
         cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
             Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));

            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}




// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
//  values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}




public int deleteContact() {
    try {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
 }

// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}





public ArrayList<String> getAllApps() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM "+TABLE_CONTACTS;
     ArrayList<String> apps = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            apps.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return list
    return apps;
}










  }
```

Comment: Which of those 350 lines are actually relevant?

Comment: this is full code of classsses ijust want to  show only that values in  list which are present in database in this line in Playstore class if (arraylist.equals(p.packageName))

Comment: Is it likely an array list will *ever* equal the name of a package? Are you instead trying to see if anything in the list's *contents* matches the package name?

Comment: yes i want to match package name with database

Comment: when i compare database value with pacage atthis line  if (arraylist.equals(p.packageName))  is not display any result

Comment: m i get database values coreectly???  this is correct line to compare database values with if (arraylist.equals(p.packageName))

Comment: Of course it's not correct: you're comparing *a list of values* to a *single value*.

Comment: then how i do that???

Comment: You can't think of any ways to see if a list contains a specific value?

Comment: no i just want to load only that values in listview that exist in database

Comment: how do i show that package name that are present in database